# What is the time complexity of FC_MRV algorithm?

Tags: time-complexity, constraint-satisfaction, constraint-programming

I am studying CSP and read the papers on it.I wanted to know the time complexity of Forward checking with Minium Remaining Value algorithm.

Comment: What did Russell and Norvig say about it?

Comment: He gives me example but I don't find the time complexity.Time Complexity of BT algorithm is O(d^n).

Answer (score 0):

The worst case complexity of FC-MRV is $O(n^2 d^2)$ where $n$ is the number of variables and $d$ is the number of domain size.